# Accusative vs Dative case

Tags: падежи

According to some resources I have you use the Dative case after a lot of verbs that mean an action pointed towards a person, like the "to gift" verb. For example:

Виктор мешает брату.

"брат" is in Dative case.

But at the same time I know that you use Accusative case for direct objects, i.e. the object of the action (and, subsequently, Dative for the indirect object). So in the example given above "брат" is clearly the direct object, so why isn't it in Accusative case? Is it just one of many "exceptions" that need to be remembered that go with the Dative, instead of the Accusative?

EDIT: Removed the "to hate" and "to love" verbs.

Comment: "to hate" is definitely not supposed to be used with the dative case. Only accusative

Comment: "to hate" - ненавидеть (кого? что? - винительный падеж)

Comment: the same for "to love"

Comment: It's not an "exception", it's an indication that you need to altogether drop thinking in your current terms of "direct" and "indirect" objects. They're clearly not helping.

Comment: "hate", "love" - any examples?

Comment: Wow, @NikolayErshov, thank you _so_ much for that very _helpful_ advise, it instantly cleared everything up for me.

Comment: You can be as sardonic as you like, but the answer you bested basically said the same thing. It was above all a case of trying to fill a cup that's already full.

Comment: @NikolayErshov I was sardonic, because you commend was all but helping. And, no, the answer I chose did nothing of the sort, what you did was say "your thinking is not right" which is _extremely_ helpful and productive, the answer explained why my thinking was not right.

Comment: @ mathgenius To be honest Dative can also mean a perverted form of English "for". Victor is disturbing (mixing) for his brother (to his brother). Often the english word "for" works as a crude analog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The so called law about direct and indirect objects is good only to explain things post-factum.  You cannot use the law to predict anything.  Examples:

- Виктор учит студентов физике.  (Студенты is in accusative, физика is in dative)
- Виктор преподаёт студентам физику. (Студенты is in dative, физика is in accusaive)

Note that Victor does the same thing in both cases.

You should just remember which verbs govern dative.

Comment: So, basically, Dative goes with certain verbs and all else is Accusative?

Comment: Yes, except that some verbs govern other cases, i. e. `владеть`  governs instrumental, `бояться` governs genitive.  Also, if a verb governs some case, the same verb with prefix governs the same case (i.e. since  `владеть`  governs instrumental, `овладеть` or `завладеть` also governs instrumental), don't know if there are any exceptions to this rule.

Comment: @user31264 what about the prefixed verb научить with respect to учить; would it also require dative ? What about получить which does not require dative afterwards ? Would this qualify for an exception ?

Answer (score 1):

> Виктор мешает брату. = Victor mixes [things] to his brother.

Мешает means mixes or messes. In this case the direct object is omitted. Victor mixes or messes some things with which his brother is doing something.

If you say Виктор мешает брата (accusative) this would mean Victor is mixing his brother. Like if he were cooking his brother in a pot.

Comment: In this context мешать is used in its "to bother" meaning

Comment: @mathgenius No, bother is беспокоить and it uses accusative. Мешать is to impede, hamper the actions or work of somebody, literally "to mix". If somebody does not do anything you can still bother them but you cannot мешать them.

Comment: [Yes, you can](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/мешать#.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.8C_I)

Comment: @mathgenius what the link is supposed to prove?

Answer (score 0):

Это непереходные глаголы и они требуют дательного падежа. брату не direct object.
Глагол мешать имеет два значения:
Мешать что-то - переходный: Мешать кашу.
Мешать кому-то - непереходный: Мешать брату.
[https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/мешать](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)